# Difference between two rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to calculate difference between two rows in sql developer??
Scenario is
Employee1 has two tasks so I need to calculate the difference between the start date of task1 and finish date of task2
And in 3rd row again Employee2 has two tasks so I need to calculate that difference too. Can someone help me in this please...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       start_date - lag(end_date) over (partition by employee order by start_date) as diff
from t;
```